# Vue-resource does not return data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a function in another js file like that;

```
checkEmailAvailability(email, callback) {
        Vue.http.get(BASE_URL_USER + '/check-email', {params: {email}})
            .then(response => callback(response.body.available))
            .catch(() => callback(false))
    },
```

And i use this function in validate method, but return undefined,

```
validate() {
    return Api.checkUsernameAvailability(this.username, available => {
        return available;
    });
}
```

How can i return response my API?

Comment: You can't. `checkUsernameAvailability` is asynchronous, so `validate` must be as well (to get `checkUsernameAvailability`'s `available` value).

Comment: I check some datas in validate, I've simplified. @acdcjunior

Comment: Still, that bit the `Vue.http.get` returns is not available right away, it is asynchronous, you have to wait for it somehow. Where do you call `validate()`?

Comment: In save method, like that `if(!this.validate()) return`

Comment: change `validate()` to like this `validate() {
    return Api.checkUsernameAvailability(this.username, available => {
        if(available) {"do somthing for success"} else { "do something for failed"}
    });
}`

Comment: And where do you call the `save` method?